# VBA Help. Delete Rows based on multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for some VBA help to clean up a Worksheet by deleting rows of data I do not need and keeping the rows of data I do based on multiple criteria.

I want to be able to keep any Row that equals "Subtotal:" in Column A and any Row that contains a number in column C while deleting all other rows that do not match that criteria.

[Before Cleanup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TLE2.jpg)

[Desired Result Requested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hASKh.jpg)

Comment: Do you want to `delete all rows where column C has no number value and delete all rows where column A does not equal "Subtotal:"` (i.e. you will be left with only rows which contain "Subtotal:" in column A **and** a number in column C), or do you want to be left with `all rows with job code descriptions with number values next to them and the rows that contain the String "Subtotal"` (i.e. you will be left with any row that contains "Subtotal:" **or** a number in column C)?

Comment: The desired results would be this.  ![After](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8FsW0sImRM3UGkydEdiSFZ3Njg/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function which should be able to get the job done.

So you can call the function from a sub and pass the column number you want to test (1 for "A"), the value you would like to test ("" for blank), the name of the worksheet you would like to test. The final argument is a Boolean value and if true it will delete on matching the value in the criteria, if not it will delete on anything else.

```
    Function DeleteCol(iCol As Integer, strCriteria As String, strWSName As String, bPositive As Boolean)

  Dim iLastCol As Integer
  Dim wsUsed As Worksheet

  Set wsUsed = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strWSName)
  iLastRow = wsUsed.Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
  For i = iLastRow To 1 Step -1
    With wsUsed.Cells(i, iCol)
      If bPositive Then
        If .Value = strCriteria Then .EntireRow.Delete
      Else
        If .Value <> strCriteria Then .EntireRow.Delete
      End If
    End With
  Next i

End Function
```

So to do what you requested above you could do:

```
Sub Delete()
 Call DeleteCol(1, "Subtotal:", "CoolSheetName", False)
 Call DeleteCol(3, "", "CoolSheetName", True)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try the following (commented) code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    With Worksheets("MySheetName") '<--| change "MySheetName" to your actual sheet name
        With Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("A:C"))
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>Subtotal" '<--| filter column "A" cells not containing "Subtotal"
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then .Offset(1).Resize(.rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete '<--| delete any filtered cell row
            .AutoFilter '<--| show all data back
            With .Offset(1, 2).Resize(.rows.Count - 1, 1) '<--| consider column "C" cell from header row (excluded) down
                DeleteRows .Cells, xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues '<--| delete any "constant text" cell row
                DeleteRows .Cells, xlCellTypeFormulas, xlTextValues '<--| delete any "formula text" cell row
                DeleteRows .Cells, xlCellTypeBlanks, xlTextValues '<--| delete any "blank" cell row
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Sub DeleteRows(rng As Range, cellType As XlCellType, cellsValue As XlSpecialCellsValue)
    Dim f As Range

    Set f = rng.SpecialCells(cellType, cellsValue)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then f.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Looking forward to running through these. Thanks again for all the fantastic replies.

Comment: I looked at the _desired results_ you posted: then your specs _"delete all rows where column A does not equal "Subtotal:""_ doesn't hold true!